# Open activity from WebView-javascript function clicked - android studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-webview

in `MainActivity` found my `WebView` i want show another activity when i click on button in javascript function

this code show another activiy when i click on botton1 but i want show when i click from javascrip

My MainActivity

```
public class Login  extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

My Html code

```
  <button onClick="jsMethod();">Call Java Activity Method</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function jsMethod(){
      activity.TestMethod();
       }
  </script>
```

I ask the developers to help me